# expectation values and square roots

Tags: probability

If I have an expectation value $\langle{A^{2}}\rangle$ = $\langle{B^{2}}\rangle$, is it possible to take the square root of both sides, and say that $\langle{A}\rangle$ = $\langle{B}\rangle$ ?

Comment: Use `\langle \rangle` to produce $\langle \cdots \rangle$.

Comment: @Sigur:  OK, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help: $E[A^2]=Var(A)+E[A]^2$

$\implies E[A^2]-Var(A)=E[A]^2$

$\implies \sqrt{E[A^2]-Var(A)}=E[A]$

Do you know the variance of $A$ or $B$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't

Comment: It sounds like the answer to my question is most likely no, since I don't have that information...

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the problem in more detail, we'd be able to help

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $B=|A|$. $ $ $ $ $ $